# Is there anyway to get driver commands from a windows driver .sys

Tags: windows, drivers, kernel

Is there anyway to Sniff out driver commands for a (.sys)system file driver?

Comment: Take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn641617

Comment: cool what about with a debugger, can i retrieve commands?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "driver commands", and how were you planning to send them to the FSD?

What is the "higher level" goal are you trying to accomplish here? And which FSD are you concerned with?

As enumerated in the link given by duDE (which is the FSD portion of the Windows Driver Kit doc), all FSDs must implement a set of required I/O functions and device IO control codes (called "File System Control Codes" because they all start with FSCTL). Some FSDs may implement unique FSCTLs or IOCTLs to allow requesting FSD-specific functions.

However you can't send most of those to an FSD from user mode, not by any means I know of. They are generated by other components in the system, like the volume managers. Another kernel driver could send them, however.

WinDbg can easily tell you which major function codes are implemented (just inspect the FSD's driver object), but not the minor function codes, nor the FSCTLs - the only way to get those would be by spelunking through the disassembly. Then, to learn what they actually *do* would take a *lot* of spelunking. I should warn you that FSDs are among the largest and most complex drivers in the OS... other than graphics drivers and acpi.sys.